# Joining Table Values

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

So far i have a list of employees who have customers attached to them and how many.

```
SELECT Employee.FirstName || ' ' || Employee.LastName AS 'Employee Name'
, COUNT(SupportRepID) AS 'No. Of Accounts'
FROM Employee
Join Customer
On Customer.SupportRepID = Employee.EmployeeID
Group By EmployeeID
```

The end output i would like is this and also to have the total revenue from invoices for each employee. This means I need the total invoices for each customer to be counted then the total invoice for all customers attached to an employee be counted. I've counted the invoices for each customer below:

```
SELECT InvoiceID
FROM Invoice
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

I have a vague idea but i don't know how to join tables very well any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: your code makes little sense..... can you give some reproducible data snippets?

Answer (score 0):

I am making a few guesses here, as I don't see how your "Invoice Value" query works, so I assumed that it was missing bits.  Basically I think you want to add your Invoice Value query to your original query, to merge the results?

If this is the case then you could use a sub query, like this:

```
SELECT 
    e.Employee.FirstName || ' ' || e.Employee.LastName AS 'Employee Name',
    COUNT(c.SupportRepID) AS 'No. Of Accounts',
    SUM(i.InvoiceValue) AS 'Value Of Invoices'
FROM 
    Employee e
    INNER JOIN Customer c ON c.SupportRepID = e.EmployeeID
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            CustomerID,
            SUM(InvoiceValue) AS InvoiceValue
        FROM 
            Invoice
        GROUP BY 
            CustomerID) i ON i.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
GROUP BY 
    e.EmployeeID
```

Note that I changed the logic of your "Invoice Value" query, and I had to take a guess at what column might hold the value.